# Write a loop that populates an array with some random numbers

Tags: php, arrays

I have previously written the code below with a loop to echo the keys of a two dimensional array.

```
$coordinates = array(
   "x"=>array(1,2,3),
   "y"=>array(4,5,6)
);

foreach($coordinates as $xycoordinates => $position){
  echo "Position: ". $xycoordinates."<br/>";
  foreach($position as $key => $value){
     echo $value;
  }
  echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

I'm trying to populate the array with some random numbers. Each attempt keeps referencing 'array push', which isn't a loop (or can array push be used in a loop?).

Comment: whats the final array's structure do you want to get?

Comment: It doesn't have to be structured just to populate the already existing array with some random numbers was the brief,thanks. So just to echo the array with a few extra random numbers really.

Comment: array_push should work just fine. You can use it inside the loop.

Comment: Rather than specifying `1,2,3`, why are you not simply calling `rand()`? i.e. `$coordinates = array(
   "x"=>array(rand(),rand(),rand()),
   "y"=>array(rand(),rand(),rand())
);`

Comment: I get that rand is  random number but I have never used it before I have only worked with populated arrays so far and the array had to be 2 dimensional with numerical values and the loop was to add a few random numbers to the array. Don't think of it as a properly working piece of code more as a class exercise just to get me familiarwith the concept.

Comment: What would be the Syntax to use array push in a loop?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys I think I know where I'm at on writing the loop and and learned that you can use array_push in a loop. May your lives be as awesome  as Tom Hiddleston's laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: in code below,

```
$Anynumber = 10;
```

this statement is simply creating a variable i.e. declaring and allocating memory space and also initializing it with value '10' ,

```
$Array = array();
```

In this statement, an array is being declared but NOT initialized with any value, in php Array can increase and decrease their size as per requirement,

```
for($index=0 ; $index<$Anynumber; $index++)
```

this is simple 'for' loop, from 0 to 9 as condition is " less than $Anynumber which is 10,

```
$Array[] = $index;
```

This statement is simply assigning $index's value which is increased at each iteration of 'for' loop,

e.g.

$Array[] = $index; // at first iteraion its like this $Array[0] = 0;

$Array[] = $index; // at second iteraion its like this $Array[1] = 1;

$Array[] = $index; // at third iteraion its like this $Array[2] = 2;

and so on.

I hope this cleared any confusion you had.

complete code:

```
$Anynumber = 10;
$Array = array();
for($index=0 ; $index<$Anynumber ; $index++){

$Array[] = $index;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Talha, very much appreciated I'll get going at it now.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
$size = 3;

$coordinates = array(
   "x"=>array(),
   "y"=>array()
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size ; $i++) {

  array_push($coordinates["x"], rand(1,10));
  array_push($coordinates["y"], rand(1,10));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have kind of answered 2 questions for me there :)